# Find/replace on .doc batch?

Tags: vba, batch-file, replace, ms-word

I'm trying to do a find-and-replace algorithm across a huge batch of .doc files (roughly 200 files).

I need to find and replace about 40 strings.  I'll need to perform such operations regularly, so I feel it would be a very good case in which to create a script.

1. Is it possible to do this via word?
2. If not, is it possible to do this with a .batch file?
3. If not, where should I get started?

Comment: You could record a macro that captures you doing the action once. Then you can use that vb code and add some more code to it to do it in batch for a whole directory for example.

Comment: You would create a macro in word that enumerated the files, opened them, did the replace then saved them back to disk. You would not require the use of a batch file, nor could a batch file accomplish this on its own.

Comment: @AlexK. Are you saying I should do everything via a Microsoft Word macro, the in-program scripting?

Comment: @PoeHaH So you are saying I should create a macro in MS Word that completes the action, and then I should create a .batch script which runs the macro against the paths of all the target files?

Comment: No. You can record the macro that captures the action, that way, you have the script code to do what you want. THEN, you can enhance this macro to do this action for all files in a certain directory.

I did something like this in excel once. First capture my action. Then make a button on the spreadsheet. Then make a macro that is called when button is clicked. That macro will run the first created macro "in batch" (for every excel file in a dir.)

Comment: @PoeHaH I will need to find the info on how to perform the operation in batch, though, right?  I'm about to take off....  You wouldn't happen to have that code on-hand?

Comment: THe comment below is of help (not my comment though. he was faster). I don't have that code with me here, but if you still need it if the below thing doesn't work, I can fetch it later and put it here. Just let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only non-trivial bit is the replace, but you can record & modify that

```
Sub Foo()
'path 
Const PATH As String = "C:\xxx\"
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim fn As String: fn = Dir$(PATH & "*.doc")
With Application
    'loop matching files
    Do While Len(fn)
        'open
        Set doc = .Documents.Open(PATH & fn)
        'replace text
        replaceInDoc doc, "OLD TEXT", "NEW TEXT"
        replaceInDoc doc, "MORE OLD TEXT", "MORE NEW TEXT"
        'save, close
        doc.Save
        doc.Close
        'get next file
        fn = Dir$()
    Loop
End With
End Sub

Sub replaceInDoc(doc As Word.Document, find As String, replaceWith As String)
'do the replace
With doc.Content.find
    .Text = find
    .Replacement.Text = replaceWith
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End Sub
```

Obviously test this on a copy.

Comment: On this line: `Dim fn As String: fn = Dir$(PATH & "*.doc")`, is there any way to go through the subdirectories, also?

Comment: Also, what language is this?  I'd like to see if there are some other useful functions.  Some of the strings I want to find and replace have special formatting (for example, they are found nested in a table, and I want to replace with an additional table row).

Comment: Its VBA; the macro language. To look at all subfolders you would need a recursive search; http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/recursive_folder_search.html - You cannot really modify document structure with find/replace, that would require different code to identify & edit the table

Answer (score 0):

In my view, there are two alternatives:

1. Create your own VBA script code to do this. You can use built into VBA editor for MS Office help system to learn about which properties and functions of MS Word Document Object Model you must employ in order to complete the task.
2. Find and use some third-party commercially available software for this job. There exists several programs from different vendors for this task.

The second approach requires considerably less time and efforts. Batch file will not do the work, unless you'll manage to control MS Word via OLE automation to access the documents in which text needs to be replaced.